# CiviCRM with Drupal Notifications for Donations

Tags: drupal, email

I am having trouble configuring Drupal/CiviCRM to send notification receipts and donation confirmation emails. This was working until recently.

Comment: It should just be civicrm taking care of sending receipts for payments for a civicrm contribution page. make sure you have receipts turned out. test your outgoing mail eg by sending your own contact a record. check you have Scheduled Jobs turned on and cron is running etc

Comment: @jenna - if you can add a few more details about your set up, e.g. what you have configured in Administer > System Settings > Outbound email and what was working and how it has stopped, any error messages, etc. that will help people help you.